# How to submit form in new tab if a specific field is filled otherwise submit normally?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a requirement in which I have to submit a form in new tab if a specific field in the form is filled (not empty) and if that specific field is empty then submit normally (no need for new tab).

I have tried but its not submitting in new tab if field is filled:

```
$("#btnAddInvc").click(function() {
if ($('#txtClaimNo').val() == '') {
    return true;
} else {
    frmAddNewInvc.form.target = '_blank';

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#frmAddNewInvc')[0].reset();
        return false;
    }, 100);
}
```

});

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following code:

```
$("#btnAddInvc").click(function() {
    if ($('#txtClaimNo').val() == '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        $('#frmAddNewInvc').attr('target', '_blank');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#frmAddNewInvc')[0].reset();
            return false;
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

Thanks.